# How can I set what i3 returns as the window manager name?

Tags: window-manager, gui, i3, window-management, window-title

I'm trying to run the Quartus Prime Lite software, however no GUI shows when I try to run it after installing. I read that its possibly because my window manager (i3) is returning a non-standard window name and Quartus can't understand it.

This question shows setting the WM name to fix a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486147/java-web-start-application-shows-empty-window-on-xmonad

How can I make i3 report a different window manager name to Quartus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change window manager name with `wmname` tool, eg:

```
$ wmname LG3D
```

Comment: Perfect. Unfortunately it didn't fix the Quartus problem but it did indeed rename the window manager.